# How to Search a particular array from a json object in a json file in angular?

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

I want to search an array using a particular json object in a json file.

This is my json file.

```
{
 "data": [
      {
        "QueryID": "203972",
        "Query_Ref_No": "2019_06749",
        "Description": "cannot access files",
        "Location": "NULL"
      },
       {
        "QueryID": "203973",
        "Query_Ref_No": "2019_06751",
        "Description": "cannot access files",
        "Location": "NULL"
      }
}
```

Below is my .html code for search. Here , i have used ion-searchbar which will take input and search through the json data and filters the array with the matched result.

```
<ion-searchbar
  animated
  icon="search"
  inputmode="numeric"
  showCancelButton="never"
  autocomplete="on"
  autocorrect="on"
  (ionInput)="filterItems($event)"
  (ionCancel)="onCancel()"
  placeholder="Enter Request No">
</ion-searchbar>
```

Below is my .ts file. Here, filterItems(event) function will be called when user enters into searchbar.
I have used function searchData() to get whole json data from json file.
Now I want to filter data on the basis of QUERY_REF_NO.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-connect-to-solve-details',
  templateUrl: './connect-to-solve-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./connect-to-solve-details.component.scss'],
})
export class ConnectToSolveDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public router: Router, private http: HttpClient, private c2s: ConnectToSolveService) { }

  response: any =  []
  rev: any = []
  id: any

  searchdata: any[]
  items: any[]
  itemsarray: any[]

  result: any = []


  searchData()
  {
    this.http.get("/assets/data/C2S/concern_status.json").subscribe((searchdata: any) => {
     this.searchdata = searchdata.data;
     this.items = this.searchdata;
     //console.log(this.searchdata)
     console.log(this.items)
     })
     //return this.response
  }

  filterItems(event)
  {
    
   this.searchData();
   const val = event.target.value;
   if(val && val.trim() !== '')
    {
      this.itemsarray = this.items.filter((item) => (this.items.values["Query_Ref_No"].indexOf(val) > -1))
    console.log(this.itemsarray)
    }
    else{
      //this.isItemAvailable = false;
    }
   //console.log(event)
  }

 

}
```

I am getting error as: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

It would be of great help if anyone would tell how to search this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to wait for `searchData()` to complete before moving ahead with filtering.

Comment: Yes. searchData() is giving all the json data and is working fine. Then i wanted to filter from that data

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(this.items)` inside the `if` condition in the `filterItems` function?

Comment: From `console.log(this.items)` in searchData(),  I am getting all the json data e.g QueryID, Query_Ref_No, Description etc
Now, I want to search through Query_Ref_no and return the array with corresponding QueryID, Query_Ref_No, Description etc.

Comment: Seems unlikely, your error message indicates that `this.items` is undefined.

Comment: Inside the if condition in the filterItems, I am not getting anything as Typeerror is coming for filter function

Comment: You have some syntax errors in the way you've written your `.filter` function as well, check if my answer helps. You just need `item["Query_Ref_No"]` and not `this.items` inside the `.filter` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can have `searchData` return the promise and `await` it inside the `filterItems` function.

```js
  searchData() {
    return this.http
     .get("/assets/data/C2S/concern_status.json").subscribe()
  }

  async filterItems(event) {
   try {
     const response = await this.searchData();
     this.searchData = response;
     this.items = response.data;
     const val = event.target.value;
       if(val && val.trim() !== '') {
         this.itemsarray = this.items.filter((item) => items["Query_Ref_No"].indexOf(val) > -1)
         console.log(this.itemsarray)
       }
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: In searchData() function, you haven;t used => after subscribing to searchdata
This error is coming

Comment: Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.